# High power, wideband balun transformer

Tags: rf, antenna, high-power, balun

I wish to design a 'somewhat'(ill-defined; i take what i can get) compact balun connected from a coax cable to a custom design dipole antenna. The design of the antenna is wideband in the sub 1 GHz regime. Since we work at high power, up about 200-300 watt, we must have cooling of the system as well for the balun.

Currently, we use a short [tapered balun](https://www.antenna-theory.com/definitions/taperedbalun.php) (to short theoretically, but limited practically) but the antenna radiates backward quite alot from this balun. My question: how to optimize the balanced to unbalanced transformation from my coax to antenna with above in mind? It should atleast be able to handle high power and be widebanded. I would like it to be short, in which the tapered balun would be to long (several wavelength in the link would be several meters in our case), but if that is needed so be it.

Comment: what are the actual frequencies involved, including any that you will not use? There may be things that can be done with lengths of line that are not truly wideband but might meet your needs.

Comment: How are you going to compensate for the massive change in impedance presented by the dipole over such a significant bandwidth. That seems to be your real problem.

Comment: Let's assume your only problem is the balun engineering - you can 'wideband' (there is no noun that cannot be verbed!) a high frequency balun with ferrite. At high frequencies, it doesn't see the ferrite, and works like a transmission line balun. At lower frequencies, the ferrite loading 'lengthens' the lines electrically. At very low frequencies, the ferrite takes over and you have effectively a flux-coupled transformer. At high powers, you might have a problem with dissipation in the ferrite.

Comment: @Neil_UK 0.3 - 900 GHz. Since we work at 200-300 W, I guess ferrite would suffer but with active cooling maybe it could work?

Comment: @Andy aka yes, this is also an issue, with many others. But we know more of these issues than the 'balun' which we have less experience of, and still is a headache. So I am investigating possibilities within this issue to get a better understanding of it.

Comment: 900 GHz is beyond anything I can remotely help on.

Comment: 900 GHz would require remarkably small features in the balun, or at least be transparent in the far infrared

Comment: 900 MHz, my appologies, a typo.